# Java: Can throwing an exception throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible for the act of throwing an exception to throw a different exception instead?

In order to throw an exception one must (optionally) allocate the new object, and call its constructor (which implicitly calls fillinstacktrace). In some cases, it sounds like addSupressed is also called. So what happens if there isn't enough memory? Is the JVM garuenteed to preallocate builtin exceptions? For instance, will (1/0) ever throw an OutOfMemoryError instead of an ArithmeticException?

Also, the constructor is a method call and hence can freely throw other exceptions. What happens in this case? Do builtin exceptions ever throw? Even if you don't explicitly throw, it seems possible to get a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class MyStupidException extends Exception {
  public MyStupidException() {
    throw new RuntimeException("whoooo");
  }
}
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
  throw new MyStupidException();
}
```

prints:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: whoooo

So, yes :-)

In the case of built in exceptions, there's a multitude of things that can go wrong.  I do not believe that the spec requires the JVM to guarantee exception allocation succeeds, so an `OutOfMemoryError` sounds like a distinct possibility.  There's also more obscure problems, such as class loading failures, that could happen.  We can also get into the downright esoteric, where someone has modified `java.lang.Exception` to cause an exception or error to throw.

So, my opinion would be that you should expect / plan for that it is possible for exception handling to itself cause exceptions in extremely rare cases.

Comment: While entirely correct, I don't think this was quite what he was asking.

Comment: What about built in exceptions?

Comment: @Charles: The question was "Is it possible for the act of throwing an exception to throw a different exception instead?", so it is answering the question as stated.  If the intent is different, then we should update the question :-)

Comment: The question is poorly worded, certainly.

I think his question is really what happens in certain edge cases when one exception is supposed to be thrown, but another interferes with it. i.e. a NumberFormatException is going to be thrown, but the JVM runs out of memory and so throws an OutOfMemoryException.

Or the constructor for your subclassed exception throws some RuntimeException.

Rather than "Is it possible to wrap an exception in another Exception type?"

Comment: I've expanded on my answer a bit.

Answer (score 4):

If not enough space for creating `ArthimeticException` object, it will through `OutofMemoryError` because JVM has no way to proceed except exiting the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can get

```
Error err = null;
throw err; // triggers a NPE.
```

or

```
// use up almost all the memory
throw new RuntimeException(); // throws OutOfMemoryError instead.
```

Comment: Yes but throw null is documented behavior, not a side effect of exception handling.

Comment: The side effects are documented as well. Are you looking for any undocumented "features"? Do you have problem in mind where you have seen unexpected behaviour?

Comment: "This specification cannot predict where internal errors or resource limitations may
be encountered and does not mandate precisely when they can be reported. Thus,
any of the VirtualMethodError subclasses defined below may be thrown at any
time during the operation of the Java virtual machine:" - Well I guess that answers the question for built in exceptions. Strangely, it doesn't mention anything about fillinstack trace. I guess this is an oversight.

Comment: filling in the stack trace is done internally and doesn't use heap memory immediately.